# RecyclerView item don't adjust it's height when scroll the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here is my situation: I am using a nested recyclerview. I have a list built with RecyclerView, and I have another horizontal recyclerView as the list item inside.

The inner recyclerView contains some objects. While not all the item have the same height. The height changes according to the content itself.

My problem is: when I scroll the inner RecyclerView, I see its item can't adjust height automatically. Instead sometimes some content is hidden and I can't see the whole of it.

Any way to fix this issue? If my description is not enough, I will provide a buildable project as demostration.

Comment: paste your code which you have tried @Anthonyeef

Comment: will you show us screenshots of it ??